# Android system dialog causes app to crash

Tags: android

My app has this line of code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before it calls this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
```

My problem is that when the app crashes (for whatever reason), Android shows a Crash Data dialog the next time it starts, causing it to crash with the error "requestFeature() must be called before adding content". Is there a workaround for this?

EDIT: The issue is that the system is adding content to the screen before I call requestfeature() causing my application to crash.

Comment: Are you using these statements within dialog onCreateDialog() or activitie's oncreate()?

Comment: Context. Post more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Dont call `setContentView` before `requestWindowFeature`

**Use Like**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
```

Comment: this methods used with the dialog.

Comment: then dialog have same methods

Comment: I am doing exactly what you are saying. The issue here is that the system is creating a dialog before I call requestWindowFeature, adding content to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for this feature before you inflate the view itself.
When using this way:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
```

You are saying something like - "Please inflate a layout named R.layout.home.layout, and inflate it with no title bar"

Comment: I am doing exactly what you are saying. Please see my comment above.